# how to change camera view of a player?

Tags: game-engine

You guys know that when you play games, you can see whats happening around you right?how do you change the camera view so that your camera is on the head of the character and not behind the character?

Comment: He asked how to change the view not how to rotate the camera (the mentioned answer). Regardless of that the question needs some clarification: Do you want to switch (or transit) in-game from third-person-view to first-person-view? Or do you want to know where to place the camera in Blender (before starting the game) to get the first-person-view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parent the camera to the player object by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>,
then move the camera where you want it by pressing <kbd>G</kbd>.